# Prove a subbase for this topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set. We define the following topology on $X$:

$$\tau=\{S\subseteq X:X\setminus S\text{ is finite}\} \cup \{0\}$$

Prove $\{X\setminus\{x\}:x \in X\}$ is a subbase of this topology.

Comment: You get $\in$ with `\in` and $\setminus$ with `\setminus`; you can always right-click on a formula and select `Show Math As` and then `TeX Commands` to see how something was produced.

Comment: i wrote \in originally but didnt work.

Comment: You may not have had the entire expression enclosed in dollar signs.

Comment: Ok i'll just have to get used to this i reckon, thanks though.

Comment: what are the set of intersections though?

Comment: I’ve converted the comment to an answer and added a bit to address your last question.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do here is check that $\mathscr{S}=\{X\setminus\{x\}:x\in X\}$ really does generate $\tau$, and this is easy: the base generated by $\mathscr{S}$, which is the set of intersections of finitely many members of $\mathscr{S}$, is already all of $\tau$, and taking unions doesn’t add any sets.

If $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is a finite subset of $X$, what is

$$\bigcap_{k=1}^n\left(X\setminus\{x_k\}\right)\;?$$

Comment: 0 i would of thought, surely thats not including any of it?

Comment: @andwil: I’m not sure what you mean; what’s not including any of what?

Comment: i mean surely there is no intersection?

Comment: @andwil: There certainly is a non-empty intersection, unless $X$ is the finite set $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. Take $X=\Bbb Z^+$ as an example; what is $$\bigcap_{k=1}^n(\Bbb Z^+\setminus\{k\})\;?$$

Comment: 1? I don't think i get it lol

Comment: @andwil: $\Bbb Z^+\setminus\{1\}$ contains every positive integer except $1$, and $\Bbb Z^+\setminus\{2\}$ contains every positive integer except $2$, so both sets contain $3,4,5,\dots$: $$(\Bbb Z^+\setminus\{1\})\cap(\Bbb Z^+\setminus\{2\})=\{k\in\Bbb Z^+:n\ge 3\}\;.$$ Can you see what happens when I now intersect this with $\Bbb Z^+\setminus\{3\}$?

Comment: $$\{k\in\Bbb Z^+:n\ge 4\}\ $$

Comment: @andwil: That’s right. And in general you get every element of $X$ that isn’t removed by one of the sets $X\setminus\{x_k\}$, so you get all of $X$ except $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$.

Comment: So is that the proof then? sorry... so if $$X\setminus\{x_k\}$$  gives us all of x except for the subset due to the intersection then this is a subbase for the given topology?

Comment: Or do i also have to prove that the unions soesn't add any sets?

Comment: \bigcup_{k=1}^n(X+\setminus\{x})=0

Comment: @andwil: To show that $\mathscr{S}$ is a subbase for $\tau$, you have to show that the set of finite intersections of members of $\mathscr{S}$ is a base for $\tau$. In this case you can show that the set of finite intersections of members of $\mathscr{S}$ is $\tau$ itself, which is certainly a base for $\tau$! The fact that taking unions adds no sets follows from the fact that $\tau$ is a topology.

Comment: Brilliant... Thank you

Comment: @andwil: You’re welcome.